# NLP Parser in Haskell

Tags: haskell, nlp

Does Haskell have a good 
(a) natural language parser
(b) part of speech tagger
(c) nlp library (a la python's nltk)

Comment: c code with well tested haskell bindings for speed would be a plus

Comment: NB You can edit your question, no need to make additions via comments.

Comment: Chatter does POS tagging and a few other things, and ships with trained models: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/chatter

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have a look at Hackage:

- [Hackage#Natural Language Processing](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/pkg-list.html#cat:natural%20language%20processing)

and

- [Dao program: An interactive knowledge base, natural language interpreter](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/Dao).

Comment: gf has a parser, but i couldn't find any others. have you used it, or anything else?

Answer (score 5):

Try [sequor](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sequor) for the POS tagger.  You could also try [brillig](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/brillig), my toy implementation of the Brill tagger, but really sequor is likely to be better.

I don't know of any parsers.  I had started working on a package called [chartparser](http://darcsden.com/kowey/chartparser) which has an CKY and Early implementation (for CFG) along with an interactive debugger, but I never really got around to finishing it or releasing it.

It could be worth asking in the [Haskell NLP](http://projects.haskell.org/nlp/) list.  There's no do-it-all library, but do have a look on Hackage, as dbhelix suggests